# C++ timer with only pthreads

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

Is there any way to write a timer in pure C/C++ with only using pthreads neither boost nor Qt.
I want OS to run only the function in the relevant thread(e.g MyThreadClass.myfunction()). I don't want to check the signal in every thread(there must be 1 type of thread cheking time). The timer thread must run (by interrupting other processes and threads) at the time as soon as possible and be able to calculate the time elapsed at it is not running. And it must not use while(true) like loops I don't want to make CPU busy.

For example I set my thread to run in 100ms. It goes background and checks time. It should run frequent but short. At 100ms it will interrupt threads and runs a particular function.

Comment: You should define what *"it will interrupt threads"* mean to you. And you should also tell if we can use other things (e.g. Linux syscalls).

Comment: So, you want to run some function periodically?

Comment: Server runs Linux based OS so we can use system calls(but if there is any POSIX standard calls I prefer them). By saying interrupt I mean notifying or running the timer thread immediately

Comment: Yes but i want to do it in the most minimal duration after the real-time.

Comment: @10qn: If you create a thread and give it real-time scheduling class, then create a timer in that thread, the operating system will do its very best to run it at the scheduled time with minimum delay. You may need to set the timeout value some number of nano or micro seconds before the actual desired timeout to ensure the thread is awake when needed, because the timer specifications are always to wake at or after the requested time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be more specific about why you need to use only pthreads. The following uses `librt` which is part of the included system libraries on most POSIX systems.

Sounds like you want to use [`timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) with the `SIGEV_THREAD` argument. That will create a thread and run a specified function when the timer expires.

Comment: The cause is that I'm working on a really strict server system. And I cannot compile my libraries since my space is very small to compile libraries like boost.